# BroadcastReceiver fires after the activity is already created

Tags: android, usb, broadcastreceiver

I want to use a BroadcastReceiver to get permission to communicate with a USB device. I am trying to implement it the same way it is done on android website http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html
It all works, kind of.
But the broadcastReceiver is fireing only after the main activity is created. Which means I am able to communicate with the device only after close the app and open it again (when I don't unregister the broadcastReceiver, when I do I can't communicate at all).
What can be the reason?
My code is like this:

private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) 
        {
            synchronized (this) 
            {
                device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) 
                {
                    if(device != null)
                    {

           //things I do when the permission is granted             

                    }

                } 
                else 
                {
                    devMessage = "permission denied for device ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The part of the code where I register it:

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
    mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);       

    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext())
        {
            device = deviceIterator.next();
            mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);             
        }

            // ...      

    if(device!=null)
    {
      // ...
    }
    else
    {
      // ...
    }
    tv.setText(devMessage);
    }
```

Does anyone know why is this happening, what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're registering your broadcast receiver in you activity. That means that before you run that activity, you cannot receive broadcasts.

You should probably look at registering a reciever-tag in in you AndroidManifest.xml. 
[This is the docs for the receiver-tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html). This allows you to register receivers without starting your activity.

This part is important:

> The <application> element has its own enabled attribute that applies to all application components, including broadcast receivers. The <application> and <receiver> attributes must both be "true" for the broadcast receiver to be enabled. If either is "false", it is disabled; it cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Thanks, that actually solves the problem (although I still don't get it - the thing I've done was just copy-paste from android website about obtaining permission to communicate with a USB device)

Comment: @Magda, the main difference is that the OS is able to start the BroadcastReceivers on its own if they are defined in your manifest. The way the example showed, you register them in the startup of your application, therefore requiring you to actually start your app in order for them to be registered.

BroadcastReceivers have their own life cycles, so they don't need to be registered in your activities. I'm guessing the example wasn't really aimed at having persistant receivers? :)