# Android usb enumeration

Tags: android, permissions, usb, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I am writing an android USB host application for which I am trying to enumerate the devices connected with tablet. I follow the code in the android USB host documentation in the developer site.

My code is as follows

**AndroidUSBActivity**

```
public class AndroidUSBActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    USBClass usb = new USBClass();
    ArrayList<String> deviceList = usb.GetUSBDevices(getBaseContext());
    final CharSequence[] items = deviceList.toArray(new CharSequence[deviceList.size()]);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select a Reader");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            String selectedDevice = (String) items[item];
            dialog.dismiss();

            TextView DeivceName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            DeivceName.setText(selectedDevice);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
}
```

**USBClass**

```
public class USBClass {


private static UsbManager mManager = null;
private static HashMap<String, UsbDevice> mdevices;
private static PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION =
        "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if(device != null){
                        //call method to set up device communication 
                        Log.i("usb", "permission granted for device " + device);
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    Log.i("usb", "permission denied for device " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};   


public ArrayList<String> GetUSBDevices(Context context){
    mManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    mdevices = new HashMap<String, UsbDevice>();
    ArrayList<String> deviceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    context.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);


    // check for existing devices
    for (UsbDevice device :  mManager.getDeviceList().values()) {
        String deviceName = null;
        UsbDeviceConnection connection = null;
        if(device.getVendorId() == 0x0123){
            mManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
            connection = mManager.openDevice(device);
            byte rawBuf[] = new byte[255];
            int len = connection.controlTransfer(0x80, 0x06, 0x0302, 0x0409, rawBuf, 0x00FF, 60);
            rawBuf = Arrays.copyOfRange(rawBuf, 2, len);
            deviceName = new String(rawBuf);
            deviceList.add(deviceName);
            mdevices.put(deviceName, device);
        }

     }
    context.unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
    return deviceList;
}
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
06-13 10:13:54.556: D/dalvikvm(2219): Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-13 10:13:54.586: I/System.out(2219): Sending WAIT chunk
06-13 10:13:54.586: W/ActivityThread(2219): Application bri.sample is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-13 10:13:54.596: I/dalvikvm(2219): Debugger is active
06-13 10:13:54.786: I/System.out(2219): Debugger has connected
06-13 10:13:54.786: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:54.986: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:55.186: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:55.406: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:55.596: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:55.796: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:55.996: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:56.206: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:56.406: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:56.645: I/System.out(2219): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 10:13:56.846: I/System.out(2219): debugger has settled (1337)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219): exception in UsbManager.openDevice
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219): java.lang.SecurityException: User has not given  permission to device   UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/004,mVendorId=1254,mProductId=20758,mClass=0,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mInterfaces=[Landroid.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;@41679100]
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager$Stub$Proxy.openDevice(IUsbManager.java:340)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.hardware.usb.UsbManager.openDevice(UsbManager.java:250)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at  bri.sample.USBClass.GetUSBDevices(USBClass.java:66)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at bri.sample.AndroidUSBActivity.onCreate(AndroidUSBActivity.java:19)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-13 10:13:57.116: E/UsbManager(2219):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 10:13:57.566: D/dalvikvm(2219): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
06-13 10:14:04.266: D/AndroidRuntime(2219): Shutting down VM
06-13 10:14:04.266: W/dalvikvm(2219): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a531f8)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bri.sample/bri.sample.AndroidUSBActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at bri.sample.USBClass.GetUSBDevices(USBClass.java:68)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at bri.sample.AndroidUSBActivity.onCreate(AndroidUSBActivity.java:19)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-13 10:14:04.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     ... 11 more
```

**PROBLEM**

I have the device plugged in and then I install the application. The **first time** when the application launches, it gets crashed.

Comment: this is the similar issue from the below link. kindly help i dont understand the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450473/broadcastreceiver-fires-after-the-activity-is-already-created/10450627#10450627n

Comment: Does [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) print out anything?

Comment: I have the same problem, only happens the first time. When I unplug and again plug in the device, it works fine.. Not even restarting the Activity.

Answer (score 16):

The crash comes when you are trying to access the device with

```
connection = mManager.openDevice(device);
```

It crashes because it is throwing a `SecurityException` because you haven't obtained permission from the user to use the device. It looks like you tried to obtain permission from the user in the line before this

```
mManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
```

But you need to understand that the call to `requestPermission()` is asynchronous. It doesn't return immediately with the permission. What it does is that it shows the user a dialog and asks the user if he will grant permission to your application. Once the user grants or denies permission the dialog is dismissed and the `PendingIntent` that you passed to `requestPermission()` is used to broadcast an Intent indicating the permission was granted (or not). You need to listen for this in a registered `BroadcastReceiver` and when the `onReceive()` method is called you can then examine the extras in the received `Intent` and decide how to proceed. Only if the user grants you permission can you move on to call `openDevice()`.

This sounds kinda complicated, but that's the way it works.

Basically, you need to call

```
mManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
```

and then wait until permission has been granted before you try to access the device.

Comment: Dear David i understand what u say. But what i require is that the usb functions are written as a jar library so that it can be included to build other applications. So an activity uses this usb library and provide calls to the usb apis in the library. Now that request permission being asynchronous i am unable to get the devices connected in the activity.

Comment: Since this works asynchronously, you'll have build your library asynchronously. That means that you'll need to provide an API that the user can register a 'callback listener' on. Then, the user will need to request some access, and then, when the access is available, you'll have to call the user back on his callback listener. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What is `mPermissionIntent`? Is it the activity you're in that's making the request? Or is it something else?